# Cloning AWS codecomit repo

Tags: git-config, aws-codecommit

I just started with the AWS codestar and wanted to clone the codecomit repo. I generated the username and password for the repo and had it saved.
I am trying to enter username and password but every time I get `Unable to access` error with code 403.

I have 2 question here on:

1) is there an easy way to just copy the password from .csv file which I downloaded from AWS in the git command while cloning the repo.
Typing that long password is nerve wrecking.

2) Is there a way to create a second set of git config which can be used with this repo as I already have some other git credentials saved which I do not wish to override as part of global config. Something like we do in `aws-cli` named profiles.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer from Amazon AWS forum [link](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=198356). I hope this will answer all you queries.